# One Variable for more than one Parameters in ExecuteSQL Task

Tags: ssis

I have multiple UPDATE statements inside my ExecuteSQL Task. Each one is dependent on one Vairiable e.g. MyId

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET COL_A={Something} WHERE ID=?
UPDATE TABLE_B SET COL_B={SomeTHing} WHERE ID=?
```

This Query takes MyId Variable as Parameter.

Do i need to have as many parameters as my Update Statements are OR there is a way to Have `one` shared parameter defined inside my ExecuteSQL Task

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @id int

SELECT @id = ?

UPDATE TABLE_A SET COL_A={Something} WHERE ID=@id
UPDATE TABLE_B SET COL_B={Something} WHERE ID=@id
```

Answer (score 3):

The other option is to change your Connection Manager from an OLE to an ADO.NET provider type. ADO.NET connection managers use [named parameters](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc280502.aspx) instead of `?` so you can re-use them instead of dealing with ordinal positions in the mapping tab. We often have 2 pointing to the same database, one OLE for Data Flow type components and an ADO.NET for Execute SQL Task.

```
UPDATE TABLE_A SET COL_A={Something} WHERE ID=@id;
UPDATE TABLE_B SET COL_B={SomeTHing} WHERE ID=@id;
```

Comment: @WilliamToddSalzman I saw that and felt a momentary pang of guilt. I'd have kept with your answer as mine involved more work (additional configuration to keep track of). Actually no, I'd "proc'ify" the situation to take a single parameter and let the proc do all the substitutions. ;)